# Joining the columns of a query result/range with a newline using sheets arrayformula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Here is the spreadsheet for testing: [Click here to copy](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1P6f6RTbQ8dKHYifJ__Pdyei6kMGDTjCIz9b7hnjfyUI/copy) OR [Click to View](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1P6f6RTbQ8dKHYifJ__Pdyei6kMGDTjCIz9b7hnjfyUI/edit#gid=879378099)

I have a **query result** from some other source of data.
[image]

From this table I further need to merge the B and C columns with new line (char(10)) and that must be expected to look like below

[image]

But I have tried with Arrayformula and I am not successful.

```
   =ARRAYFORMULA(query(Sheet1!A2:Z7,"Select A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H") & char(10) & query(Sheet1!A2:Z7,"select B") )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with an [{ array expression }](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276) like this:

```
=arrayformula( 
  query( 
    { Sheet1!A2:H7, Sheet1!B2:B7 & char(10) & Sheet1!C2:C7 }, 
    "select Col1, Col9, Col4, Col5, Col6, Col7, Col8", 
    1 
  ) 
)
```

...or perhaps more simply, like this:

```
=arrayformula( 
  query( 
    { Sheet1!A2:A, Sheet1!B2:B & char(10) & Sheet1!C2:C, Sheet1!D2:H }, 
    "where Col1 is not null", 
    1 
  ) 
)
```